# Event handler that executes before an item is added? (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, groups, event-handlers

I need to obtain a user group when he/she click the Add item button of a list. I mean... I want to write on one of the field of the item the user group.

I get correctly my user group, but I'm using an ItemAdding Event Handler, the problem is that I want to obtain the user group before the item is added, to writes it it on a field of the item list.

I don't know what type of event handler I have to use... Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!